# Find limit of function: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{10^{100} \cdot{7^x} + \log_{2}(x)x^2}{9^x+10^{100}x^{1000}} $

Tags: limits

Trying to find the limit for the following equation:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{10^{100} \cdot{7^x} + \log_{2}(x)x^2}{9^x+10^{100}x^{1000}} $$

I'm a little confused here. Initially I thought this would be $0$ because the denominator will increase at a greater rate to the numerator, given it increases exponentially to a greater degree ($9^x$), - however I'm unsure of how to properly work this out in a way that would stand up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Divide all the terms by $9^{x}$ and take limit for each term You should get $\frac {0+0} {1+0}=0$

Comment: Ah right that's what I tried but I think I messed up the calculations somewhere in there, thanks for the advice I'll try again.

Comment: Basic rule of thumb in limits of fractions with additions, you can pretty safely ignore any term other than the one that grows the fastest.  Since any exponential grows faster than any polynomial,  you just end up with $10^100*(\frac 7 9)^x$, which indeed goes to 0